# A better name for INeedSomething...?

Tags: c#, interface, naming-conventions, class-design, naming

I was trying pick a name for an interface through which I can pass something into an object like:

- If the object is INeedX then SetX(some x) method will be called;
- If the object is INeedY then SetY(some y) method will be called;
- and so on. (funny as hell, I know :) )

I try to find a different name for this kind of interfaces but I can't figure this out.

**Does anybody have an idea how to name the *INeedSomething* interface ?**

Comment: All classes need their base classes and the interfaces that they implement. Your question is vague, try to give an example.

Comment: The name of the interface should describe an ability or function that the object can perform, not the specifics of what data it requires to do it. That is an implementation detail, which has no business in the interface name.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an interface. And the fact that you're having difficulty naming it might also suggest you've picked the wrong tool for the job. Could you expand on what problem this is trying to solve for you? Also, if it's just a naming issue, can you post actual code the uses this (stick with INeedSomething for now)?

Answer (score 3):

What about the name **IDependsOn** for your interface (aka. IDependsOnUserId, IDependsOnTimeOut)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `INeed` interface is probably an indication of an awkward design. It seems to me that what you are really looking for is dependency injection, which is the code equivalent of stating that an object requires another object to function. So instead of having

```
class Car:INeed<Engine> {
    public Set(Engine engine)
}
```

, maybe what you really want is

```
class Car {
    public Car(Engine engine)
}
```

If I were you I would try to see if the above is applicable in your case, which is a more standard way of declaring needs/dependencies

Comment: I agree, however, if constructor injection is not possible, property injection can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface INeed<T>
{
   public T SetValue { set; }
}
```

by using generics, the type passed by your interface is defined later, like this:

```
class Needy : INeed<int>
{
   private int internalValue;
   public int SetValue { set {
     internalValue = value;
   } };
}
```

Comment: I'm not referring to the implementation of the INeedSomething, and the implementation can't be generic because the same type can mean many things like: INeed<int> can mean INeedUserId, INeedTimeout, or other value that can be int.

Comment: this won't work if you have a class like this : `class Needy : INeed<int>, INeed<string>`. Actually, this can work if you explicitly defines the members and wrap them in a per-class public property. Can be a bit weird when consuming the class with its class variable declaration ot its interface variable declaration

Answer (score 0):

IRequire sounds better, however, the use of the interface for this seems wrong.

Use attributes instead:

```
class MyClass
{
    [Required]
    double X
    {
         get;
         set;
    }
}
```